# pip install mysql-python fails with EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

Tags: python, pip, mysql-python

**This is the error I get**

```
(mysite)zjm1126@zjm1126-G41MT-S2:~/zjm_test/mysite$ pip install mysql-python
Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz (70Kb): 70Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mysql-python
    sh: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: not found

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 15, in <module>

    metadata, options = get_config()

  File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config

    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")

  File "setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config

    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))

EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/zjm1126/.pip/pip.log
(mysite)zjm1126@zjm1126-G41MT-S2:~/zjm_test/mysite$ pip install mysql-python
Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mysql-python
    sh: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: not found

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 15, in <module>

    metadata, options = get_config()

  File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config

    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")

  File "setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config

    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))

EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/zjm1126/.pip/pip.log
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: See this thread: [mysql_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface][1] worked for me :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface

Comment: I'm MAC OS user
I solve this issue whit this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940302/installing-mysql-python-causes-command-clang-failed-with-exit-status-1-on-mac

Answer (score 1602, accepted):

It seems mysql_config is missing on your system or the installer could not find it.
Be sure mysql_config is really installed.

For example on Debian/Ubuntu you must install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Maybe the mysql_config is not in your path, it will be the case when you compile by yourself
the mysql suite.

**Update:** For recent versions of debian/ubuntu (as of 2018) it is

```
sudo apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: That still created an error for me. I used `apt-get install python-mysqldb` instead.

Comment: my 2c experience: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` worked for me, `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb` did not help

Comment: @JonatanLittke Installing a global python-mysqldb kind of goes against the point of virtualenv IMO.

Comment: for Mariadb, ```sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev``` did the trick.

Comment: If these solutions don't work for you, then you might still be needing to install python-dev:
`apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: after installing `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` you might need to remove the build directory in your virtualenv. then run `pip install mysql-python` again

Comment: Fedora 19: sudo yum install mysql-devel (solved the problem for me)

Comment: I have found that the following 3 packages worked.  Of course it depends on the state of your env. but for Ubuntu 12.04, I needed to do this `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: I had to install libmysqlclient-dev AND python-dev

Comment: This is the answer I want at first place of first page in Google search results :)

Comment: I also had to install `libssl-dev`

Comment: for Mariadb + Ubuntu 14.04: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885914/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-on-ubuntu-14-04-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu. Using `libmysqlclient-dev` worked for me.

Comment: I had issues installing mysql-python using pip but this solved the problem - thanks!

Comment: On centos 7: `sudo yum install MySQL-python`

Comment: If you are on Mac, make sure you have installed mysql: `brew install mysql`

Comment: debian testing: `sudo apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: For me with MariaDB I needed to install `libmariadb-dev`, `libmysqlclient-dev` didn't work for me

Comment: @RyanHaining I've edited the answer with your variant. The accepted command doesn't work with recent distos.

Comment: Could some knowledgeable person please list all of the dependencies that need to be installed, it seems clear from the comments that people come to this answer missing a variety of dependencies, and we don't want to just install everything willy-nilly

Comment: For OS X the same is: `brew install mysql-client`

Comment: Don't forget to run `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt update` before, I just wasted 30 minutes of my life.

Comment: 9 years later and the issue is still here :)

Answer (score 324):

In Mac OS, I simply ran this in terminal to fix:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

This is the quickest fix I found - it adds it to the path, but I think you're better off adding it permanently (ie add it to `/etc/paths`) if you plan to install MySQL-python in another environment.

(tested in OSX Mountain Lion)

Comment: If you're using [bitnami's MAMP stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/mampstack) use `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/mampstack-5.3.17-0/mysql/bin` If you're using [this commercial MAMP stack](http://www.mamp.info/), on the other hand, uninstall it and get the bitnami one because it is shit and doesn't include the mysql headers.

Comment: To make the path permanent add it to the bottom of `/etc/paths` - you will need to open a new terminal window to access the new path.

Comment: @Timmmm Quite expensive solution as all of my Databases are on official version :/ is there any other way to sort this out?

Comment: Very helpful. If you're using XAMPP, use it as `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin`

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, you probably missed some of the steps described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25491082/1515819

Comment: This finally works thanks! also if `mysql` is not installed, use `brew install mysql` where the location is `/usr/local/bin/mysql` (or `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/VERSION/bin/` if it is not symlinked ).

Comment: This fixed my `pipupgrade` or doing it manually `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt && pip3 install --upgrade -r requirements.txt` Thanks!

Comment: On Mac I also had to link the libmysqlclient.18.dylib library to get past a "Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib" error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33626077/4370999

Comment: This is the best answer so far, works for me MacOS big sur v11.6

Comment: Worked like champ!

Answer (score 109):

There maybe various answers for the above issue, below is a aggregated solution.

For Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python-dev
$ sudo apt install python-MySQLdb
```

For CentOS:

```
$ yum install python-devel mysql-devel
```

Comment: Thanks for the centos tip. I've been chasing this all morning.

Comment: Maybe worth adding  `python3-dev` / `python3-devel`

Answer (score 106):

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev python-dev
```

Seemed to do the trick.

Comment: yes, for me only libmysqlclient-dev wasn't enough, python-dev was missing too.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) (32-Bit) after inplace upgrade from 10.04 (lucid) only this did solve these errors. Specially the additional "python-dev"!

Comment: Worked for me as well -- python-dev was the last piece of the puzzle. Already had python-mysqldb installed, so that's definitely not all that is needed.

Comment: Update: for Python3 you have to install `python3-dev`.

Comment: I needed to do this and also install `gcc` to get a successful install.  Also, it's probably best to not do `python-dev`, but specify the particular version such as `python2.7-dev`, `python3.6-dev`, etc.

Comment: Thanks!) Works well on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 49):

If you are on MAC
Install this globally

```sh
brew install mysql
```

then export path like this

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Than globally or in your venv whatever you like

```sh
pip install MySQL-Python
```

Note: globally for python3 as Mac can have both python2 & 3

```sh
pip3 install MySQL-Python
```

Comment: if you still get an error about mysqlclient follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025594/osx-ld-library-not-found-for-lssl

Answer (score 38):

You can use the MySQL Connector/Python

**Installation via PyPip**

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Further information can be found on the [MySQL Connector/Python 1.0.5 beta announcement](http://geert.vanderkelen.org/mysql-connector-python-1-0-5-beta/) blog.

On Launchpad there's [a good example of how to add-, edit- or remove data](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/myconnpy/1.0/view/head:/python3/examples/inserts.py) with the library.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me when I gave up on mysqldb and the missing mysql_config mess. Works well for my purposes.

Comment: @wjoba can you explain further? I am install `py-mysql2pgsql` and finding error of mysql_config thing. I am using MAMP. What does mysqk connector do?

Comment: @Volatil3 mysql-connector-python worked well as an out-of-the-box replacement for mysql-python for me. Installing the former via pip worked with no issues and got rid of the mysql_config error because (in the dev's own words) mysql connector is "pure Python and does not need any other MySQL software, thus no C libraries and compiling." Hope that helps. Try the installation mentioned in this solution and see if you still encounter the error.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14/4, I get:   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mysql-connector-python

Answer (score 29):

For **centos** users:

`yum install -y mysql-devel python-devel python-setuptools`

then

`pip install MySQL-python`

---

If this solution **doesn't work**, and print gcc compile error like:
`_mysql.c:29:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

You need to specify the path of `Python.h`, like this:
`pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/python2.6" MySQL-python`

Comment: That sounds as if you don't have the right include files for the Python binary `pip` is installing for. Python itself normally provides the include location; manually specifying the path most likely is pointing to the *wrong version*.

Comment: I had to do a ```sudo pip install MySQL-python``` due to a error: ```copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql_exceptions.py -> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
    error: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql_exceptions.py: Permission denied```

Answer (score 19):

I was trying to install `mysql-python` on an Amazon EC2 Linux instance and I had to install these :

```
yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-common mysql-libs gcc
```

But then I got this error :

```
_mysql.c:29:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

So I installed :

```
yum install python-devel
```

And that did the trick.

Comment: I used: `sudo yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-common mysql-libs gcc `outside of my virtualenv. Then, I returned to my virtual env and ran `pip install mysql-python` and it worked.

Comment: `dnf install mysql-devel gcc` was enought for me, it depends on the rest

Comment: `python-devel` will now give error, if using python 2.7 try this
`python27-devel`

Answer (score 10):

For anyone that is using MariaDB instead of MySQL, the solution is to install the `libmariadbclient-dev` package and create a symbolic link to the config file with the correct name.

For example this worked for me:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/mariadb_config /usr/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: This is an underappreciated answer useful in any case where one wants to connect to a specific, known database socket. It helped me connect to a standalone mysql database.

Most solutions here just recommend re-installing (or installing a second or third... etc) msql client!

Answer (score 9):

### For Linux

this works for me

```
yum install python-devel mysql-devel
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `sudo apt-get build-dep python-mysqldb`

Answer (score 6):

#### OSX Mavericks

Due to changes within osx mavericks & xcode development tools you may get the error on installation

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
```

therefore use :

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install mysql-python
```

Answer (score 6):

for mariadb install *lib**mariadb**client-dev* instead of *libmysqlclient-dev*

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

Comment: Just what I need when using Debian 9 Stretch with MariaDB

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in the Terraform:light container. It is based on Alpine.

There you have to install mariadb-dev with:

```
apk add mariadb-dev
```

But that one is not enough because also all the other dependencies are missed:

```
apk add python2 py2-pip gcc python2-dev musl-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

You should install the `mysql` first:

```
yum install python-devel mysql-community-devel -y
```

Then you can install `mysqlclient`:

```
pip install  mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 2):

sometimes the error depends on the actual cause. we had a case where mysql-python was installed through the python-mysqldb debian package.

a developer who didn't know this, accidentally ran `pip uninstall mysql-python` and then failed to recover with `pip install mysql-python` giving the above error.

`pip uninstall mysql-python` had destroyed the debian package contents, and of course `pip install mysql-python` failed because the debian package didn't need any dev files.

the correct solution in that case was `apt-get install --reinstall python-mysqldb` which restored mysql-python to its original state.

Answer (score 2):

Sequence to be followed.

```
pip install mysqlclient
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev
pip install configparser 
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py /usr/lib/python3.6/ConfigParser.py
```

Then try to install the MYSQL-python again. That Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

On Mac:

```
brew install mysql-client
```

locate mysql

```
mdfind mysql | grep bin
```

then add to path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-client/8.0.23/bin/
```

or permanently

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-client/8.0.23/bin/" >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue trying to install on OS X Server 10.6.8. Here's what I had to do.
Using:

MySQL-python 1.2.4b4 (source)
MySQL-5.6.19 (binary installer)
Python 2.7 (binary installer)
NOTE: Installing in virtualenv...

Unzip source, open 'distribute_setup.py' and edit DEFAULT_VERSION to use the latest version of distribute tools, like so:

```
DEFAULT_VERSION = "0.6.49"
```

Save. Open 'site.cfg' file and uncomment the path to mysql_config so it looks something like (reference your own path to mysql_config):

```
# The path to mysql_config.
# Only use this if mysql_config is not on your PATH, or you have some weird
# setup that requires it.
mysql_config = /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Now clean, build and make will not fail with the 'mysql_config' not found error.
Hope this helps someone else trying to make use of their old xserves :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your sudo path does not know about your local path... go into superuser mode, add the path, and install it from there.

```
sudo su
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
pip install mysql-python
exit
```

And you're up and running on OSX.  Now you have an updated global python.

Answer (score 1):

if you install MySQL-python in your virtual env, you should check the pip version, if the version is older than 9.0.1, please update it

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface I do not think your answer will help

Answer (score 1):

In my case my database is running on container and my flask app is running on another container when i tried updating code app got broke with error

```
   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
/bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-bya8e734/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-bya8e734/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 65, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs")
  File "/tmp/pip-build-bya8e734/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
    raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
OSError: mysql_config not found
```

Key in stack trace is

```
/bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
```

because where my flask app is running doesn't have mysql client properly configured so first i installed mysql server and then install

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7 -y
```

Then started MySQL

```
mansoor@LARC-mansur:~/Documents/clients/HR/DevopsSimulator/web$ sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Then install flask-mysql package and this time it worked

```
mansoor@LARC-mansur:~/Documents/clients/HR/DevopsSimulator/web$ sudo pip3 install flask-mysqldb
```

This is different case but posting here because may be someone else in the world facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

write on 27 Aug, 2021

my macos version is BigSur(14.4), and mysql version is mysql8. It seems like in the higher version of mysql, they delete the `my_config.h` files but change to the `mysql.h`.

so your guys should run the following shell:

```sh
cd /usr/local/include/mysql
cp mysql.h my_config.h
```

after that, run `pip install MySQL-python` and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

on MacOS Mojave, mysql_config is found at /usr/local/bin/ rather than /usr/local/mysql/bin as pointed above, so no need to add anything to path.