# Installing MySQL-python

Tags: python, mysql

I got the below failure while trying to get MySQL-python installed on my Ubuntu/Linux Box.From the below it seem like the issue is `sh: mysql_config: not found`
Could someone advice me on what to do?

```
rmicro@ubuntu:~$ pip install MySQL-python
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz (70Kb): 70Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
    sh: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/home/rmicro/build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: not found

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/home/rmicro/build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [pip install mysql-python fails with EnvironmentError: mysql\_config not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

On Ubuntu it is advised to use the distributions repository. So installing python-mysqldb should be straight forward:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

If you actually want to use pip to install, which is as mentioned before not the suggested path but possible, please have a look at this previously asked question and answer: [pip install mysql-python fails with EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-show-error)

Here is a very comprehensive guide by the developer: http://mysql-python.blogspot.no/2012/11/is-mysqldb-hard-to-install.html

To get all the prerequisites for python-mysqld to install it using pip (which you will want to do if you are using virtualenv), run this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Could explain what you really meant by that?

Comment: I think he is saying that if you install python-mysqldb as a repository package, the system will handle dependency management for you, realizing that it needs to install libmysqlclient-dev too

Comment: @user618677: `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`

Comment: Thank you all, it worked. It pretty obvious that I need to learn more of Ubuntu.

Comment: @zalun as mentioned at the end of my answer if you want to use pip (in virtualenv) you have to install the prerequisites by hand.

Comment: i am in same problem but Mac OSX. How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 15):

You have 2 options, as described bellow:

---

Distribution package like Glaslos suggested:

```
# sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

In this case you can't use virtualenv no-site-packages (default option)
but must use:

```
# virtualenv --system-site-packages myenv
```

---

Use clean virtualenv and build your own python-mysql package.

First create virtualenv:

```
# virtualenv myvirtualenv
# source myvirtualenv/bin/activate
```

Then install build dependencies:

```
# sudo apt-get build-dep python-mysqldb
```

Now you can install python-mysql

```
# pip install mysql-python
```

---

**NOTE** Ubuntu package is python-mysql**db** , python pypi package is python-mysql (without **db**)

Answer (score 8):

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Reread the error message. It says:

> sh: mysql_config: not found

If you are on Ubuntu Natty, `mysql_config` belongs to package [libmysqlclient-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mysql_config&mode=exactfilename&suite=natty&arch=any)

Answer (score 3):

Python or Python3 with MySQL, you will need these. These libraries use MySQL's connector for C and Python (you need the C libraries installed as well), which overcome some of the limitations of the mysqldb libraries.

```
   sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
   sudo apt-get install python-mysql.connector
   sudo apt-get install python3-mysql.connector
```

Answer (score 1):

1. find the folder: `sudo find / -name "mysql_config"` (assume it's `"/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin"`)
2. add it into PATH:`export PATH:export PATH=/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin:$PATH`
3. install it again

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me on python 3

### pip install mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

In python3 with virtualenv on a Ubuntu Bionic machine the following commands worked for me:

```
sudo apt install build-essential python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
pip install mysqlclient
```