# mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: mysql, django, privileges

I've started working with django, and here is the error on 'runserver' after setting up 'DATABASES' in settings.py

```
mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

My settings.py portion of code:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'my_site',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'root',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }

}
```

I've created 'my_site' database and privileges are set in the right way (root has all privileges). 
I've done this operations with 'phpmyadmin'.

What goes wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Run in console

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by 'password' with grant option;
```

Comment: i actually want to run this command through python. But I get access denied. Any idea how to automate this? Thanks

Comment: Yes, Cool. Thanks.

Comment: after running above command from mysql console, I can't even login as root now :(

Answer (score 3):

> The instruction said to add the `username` with the SQL statement as:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, LOCK TABLES ON winestores.* TO username@127.0.0.1 IDENTIFIED by 'password';
```

> After doing this as root, I quit and tried to log back in with the new user. I got the ERROR 1045. I fixed it by logging back in as root and reissuing the SQL statement again except with `username@localhost`. It worked! I don't know why? Maybe it is the difference between IPs of '127.0.0.1' and 'localhost'???

as read on [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html).

Answer (score 3):

After struggling for two days I finally found whats wrong.
                     **Entire steps to set up a mysql database for Django site are-**

> Your settings.py file must look like-

```
DATABASES = { 
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'django_db',   #Name of database you created
       'USER': 'root',        #Username of database you created
       'PASSWORD':'',         #Password of database you created
       'HOST': '',
       'PORT': '',
    } }
```

Note:-The password and username given above is of my localhost you have change it to yours.

> 1. create a database in localhost let name it *django_db* (for this you can use lamp/wamp/Xampp or mysql command prompt)
> 2. Edit the file *settings.py* and save the password you require to open your database in DATABASES field as given below in the code.
> 3. open terminal.
> 4. If you are using virtual environment then switch into it by using command ->  ***workon env_name***
> 5. Now ***cd app_name*** eg. cd mysite

step 3, 4 and 5 just tells how to reach the folder where manage.py file found in your Application.

> 6.To check you are in right directory run command ***ls -l***.  If you find manage.py file then everything is right go ahead
>
> 7.python manage.py migrate

If you are having any error like- "No module named MySQLdb" in running above command you can visit the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459766/installing-mysql-python)

> 8.python manage.py syncdb
>
> 9.python manage.py runserver
>
> 10.You will be asked for username and password for your Django admin, give whatever you want to open Django admin site.
>
> 11.check you are having some tables in your database in localhost at `http://localhost/phpmyadmin. You are good to go now.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone encountering this issue - check to make sure that the database user **host** is `localhost` . If set to `%`, it won't work, you will need to add `localhost` or change your overall security settings.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when your Username or password is wrong ....so go through the username and password once again.

Answer (score 0):

your DB doesn't recognize your root user and password.   If you can go to the phpmyAdmin and try to create a different user and password and assign to the DB, if that is not working try to create but console with create user, and grant all.

Answer (score -1):

FYI if your using XAMPP, go directly into localhost/phpmyad>Privileges to modify this