# MySQL + Django / ERROR 1045 and CommandError

Tags: mysql, django

I configured MySQL as follows:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS foodb;

CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost';
ALTER USER 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'qux';
GRANT ALL ON foodb.* to 'foo'@'localhost';
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'foo'@'localhost';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

SELECT user, host, authentication_string FROM mysql.user ORDER BY user, host;
```

When I run

```sh
python manage.py dbshell
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'foo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
CommandError: "mysql --user=foo --host=localhost foodb" returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Also, this query

```sql
SHOW GRANTS for 'foo'@'localhost';
```

returns

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for foo@localhost                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'foo'@'localhost'                      |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `foodb`.* TO 'foo'@'localhost'       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Finally, switching user to root and the root account password works just fine. So I think the issue must be with the user permissions on MySQL itself.

What additional permissions does 'foo'@'localhost' need for this to work?

Comment: check from your settings if you connecting to the correct database, maybe it point to another one like example postgresql ? or different mysql version?

Comment: also check if you encountered the following case https://stackoverflow.com/a/52121387/11225821 . Of course root user will always have default access to a database

Comment: ALTER USER 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password123' seems to have resolved the problem. Is it a MySQL version issue?

Comment: maybe, i think you have to check if your django application connect to the right mysql database first