# Access denied when Flask-migrate connects to MySQL server via SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python, alembic, flask-migrate

**TL;DR:** When I try to use `flask db migrate` with a remote database, I get: *MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)")*. But I'm certain that the username and password are correct, the remote user has the `SELECT` privilege, and I don't actually have any models declared yet.

---

I have an SSH tunnel set up for access to a remote database.

```
$ ssh -L <local_port>:localhost:<remote_internal_port> <mysql_user>@<server> -p <remote_external_port>
```

I have credentials for a read-only user on the remote MySQL DB (really MariaDB). This is not the database the users are stored in, so I'm using SQLALCHEMY_BINDS to add the second database.

My environment looks like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=sqlite:////tmp/dev.db
DATABASE_BINDS="remote=mysql+mysqldb://<mysql_user>:<pass>@localhost:<local_port>/<db_name>"
```

Then in the config file:

```
from environs import Env

env = Env()
env.read_env()

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = env.str("DATABASE_URL") # local
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = env.dict("DATABASE_BINDS")  # remote, etc
```

I don't presently have any models declared for the remote database at all. I'm planning to use [reflection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html) to load them.

The initial run of `flask db init --multidb` works fine. It creates the migration folder. But when I run `flask db migrate -m "Initial DB"`, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2275, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 303, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 238, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 453, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 166, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user '<mysql_user>'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

I've checked and double-checked that the username and password I've declared in the environment are correct. I can successfully use a GUI client with these settings to browse the remote MySQL database via the SSH tunnel. I can use the MySQL CLI client on the remote server to USE and SELECT on the appropriate database.

I'm at a loss for where to look here. I think the SSH tunnel is a red herring, since it's working well with the GUI client, but I don't know how to get more logging to see what the problem really is. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14683892) implies that the issue might in fact be one of permissions, not with the l/p themselves. Does Flask-Migrate require something other than the SELECT privilege?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1".