# hey how to make mysql connection in pandas as well

Tags: python, html, css

`In [2]: c=connection.cursor()` i have written so it has been

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: `OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")`

`DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'NAME':'test', 'USER':'root', 'Password':'Antimk', 'HOST':'localhost', 'PORT':'', 'OPTIONS':{ 'init_command':"SET sql_mode='STRICT_TABLES'" }`

what am I doing like this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your MySQL root password is unset. As the error states: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`, you need to set a password for the user `root` or disable the authentication. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno) to solve the problem, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181344/mysql-exceptions-operationalerror-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalh). Even if not so reproducible, the Python snippet should connect fine. Also, I suggest you not to share your passwords.