# use"pip install mysql-python" but it doesn't work, how to fix it

Tags: python, mysql

I am new to Python and I want to install mysqldb module to connect to my database, I already try "pip install mysql-python",the terminal shows:

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
The directory '/Users/suoliyun/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/suoliyun/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 1.9MB/s 
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/suoliyun/Library/Enthought/Canopy/edm/envs/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-DCyMvD/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1dVZC1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.18_1/include/mysql -I/Users/suoliyun/Library/Enthought/Canopy/edm/envs/User/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:1589:10: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
            if (how < 0 || how >= sizeof(row_converters)) {
                ~~~ ^ ~
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -g -arch x86_64 -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.18_1/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/*/Library/Enthought/Canopy/edm/envs/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-DCyMvD/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1dVZC1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-DCyMvD/mysql-python/
```

How to fix that? what doest that mean?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL installed? Because it's complaining `ld: library not found for -lssl`

Comment: There is dependency issues of `gcc`. Solve using installing `gcc`. If you are linux you can install like `sudo apt-get install gcc`

Comment: similar Question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459766/installing-mysql-python

Comment: From the logs, it's OSX. 
Ensure xcode is installed. Xcode will install required packages like gcc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are installing any project-dependent library of python always install those libraries in respective virtual environment

```
1. pip install virtualenv
```

## This will install virtualenv, now create a virtual environment named miscellaneous

```
2. virtualenv miscellaneous
```

## This will create a virtual environment named miscellaneous in working directory

```
3. source miscellaneous/bin/activate
```

## This will initiate the virtual environment and now any library you will install will be installed in this environment

```
4. pip install MySQL-python
```