# mysql-python installation failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-usR6Hj/mysql-python/

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm trying to install mysql-python using `sudo pip install mysql-python`

Instead I get the following warnings and error:

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 842kB/s 
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-Q8wg2D/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-CkqBY9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/include/mysql -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/_mysql.o
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/local/include/my_config.h:174:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_LONG' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
    #define SIZEOF_LONG      8
            ^
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:54:17: note: previous definition is here
    #        define SIZEOF_LONG             4
                    ^
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/local/include/my_config.h:179:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_TIME_T' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
    #define SIZEOF_TIME_T    8
            ^
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:57:17: note: previous definition is here
    #        define SIZEOF_TIME_T           4
                    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    _mysql.c:287:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    cmd_argc = PySequence_Size(cmd_args);
                             ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:317:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    groupc = PySequence_Size(groups);
                           ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:470:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            int j, n2=PySequence_Size(fun);
                                   ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1127:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1129:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_escape_string(out, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1168:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            size = PyString_GET_SIZE(s);
                 ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:92:32: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_GET_SIZE'
    #define PyString_GET_SIZE(op)  Py_SIZE(op)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/object.h:116:56: note: expanded from macro 'Py_SIZE'
    #define Py_SIZE(ob)             (((PyVarObject*)(ob))->ob_size)
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1178:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out+1, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1180:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_escape_string(out+1, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1274:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            if ((n = PyObject_Length(o)) == -1) goto error;
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:434:25: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_Length'
    #define PyObject_Length PyObject_Size
                            ^
    _mysql.c:1466:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            len = strlen(buf);
                                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1468:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            len = strlen(buf);
                                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1504:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                    len = strlen(buf);
                                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1506:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                    len = strlen(buf);
                                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    13 warnings generated.
    cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/_mysql.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-Q8wg2D/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-CkqBY9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-Q8wg2D/mysql-python/
```

The version of python installed on my local is: `2.7.10`

Any idea why this happens is appreciated

Comment: The [pypi history](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/#history) of this package shows its last update was in 2014, so I'm not sure how well maintained/supported it is. Furthermore, python2.7 will reach end of life on Jan 1, 2020. What are you trying to do with this package? There might be some suitable alternatives

Comment: Unfortunately it is recommended that I use 2.7 for now. I'm doing this on mac, and I was told that it could be because of not having xCode. So I'm installing it to see if it fixes the issue. I'll update this post if it does.

Comment: it didn't help!

Comment: Check this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459766/installing-mysql-python

Comment: @Gargantua OP is on a mac, so the ubuntu package repo doesn't necessarily apply here

Answer (score 0):

On my mac, I was able to `conda install` this package using a 2.7 anaconda environment. The instructions for installing anaconda can be found [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/) where they include instructions for both python 3.7 and python 2.7.

Once installed, you can create an environment using the following command:

```sh
conda create -n <name_of_your_env> python=2.7 anaconda
```

Where `anaconda` will install the anaconda suite of packages. From there, you will probably have to add anaconda to your `PATH`. If you edit your `.bash_profile` with vim like `vim ~/.bash_profile`, you should be able to add the corresponding anaconda directory to the path like so:

```sh
export PATH="/path/to/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Then you can `source activate <name_of_your_environment>` and `conda install mysql-python`.

Otherwise, I could not get a normal `pip install` to work, and downloading the wheel from conda forge doesn't seem to get around the problem either