# mysql_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface

Tags: python, linux, ssh, mysql-python

I am trying to get a Python script to run on the linux server I'm connected to via ssh. The script uses mysqldb. I have all the other components I need, but when I try to install mySQLdb via setuptools like so:,

```
python setup.py install
```

I get the following error report related to the `mysql_config` command.

```
sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

Has anyone else encountered this error and if so how did you resolve it/what can I do to successfully install mysqldb?

Comment: Hi @user904542 - I've edited your question to hopefully make it a little more concise and get you some answers :) If you don't like it, or want to provide additional details, there's an edit link directly under your question which you can use to either roll back to your original, or add to the changes I've made.

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem, because i installed mysql from source. if you do too, just run something like this to make mysql_config available: sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config /usr/bin/mysql_config or add /usr/local/mysql/bin/ to your path.

Comment: If you have already installed mysql, the above comment  by Thi Duong Nguyen solves the problem by creating a symlink to the mysql_config file in the /usr/bin directory, which is in the path that python will search.

Comment: just do this-------------apt-get install python-mysqldb

Comment: @AlexBoschmans symlinking `/usr/bin` is wrong, it is `usr/local/my...` see Thi's answer.

Comment: Mac users, read this: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

Answer (score 933):

mySQLdb is a python interface for mysql, but it is not mysql itself. And apparently mySQLdb needs the command 'mysql_config', so you need to install that first.

Can you confirm that you did or did not install mysql itself, by running "mysql" from the shell? That should give you a response other than "mysql: command not found".

Which linux distribution are you using? Mysql is pre-packaged for most linux distributions. For example, for debian / ubuntu, installing mysql is as easy as

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

mysql-config is in a different package, which can be installed from (again, assuming debian / ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

if you are using mariadb, the drop in replacement for mysql, then run

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

Reference:
https://github.com/JudgeGirl/Judge-sender/issues/4#issuecomment-186542797

Comment: Reading package lists...Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information...Done
Note, selecting libmysqlclient15-dev instead of libmysqlclient-dev
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libmysqlclient15-dev: Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages

Comment: The above is an error I got when running the "sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev" command. The error was too long to allow me to put a statement explanning what I was talking about (and so I am doing that here instead).

The key of that error seems to be this part:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: libmysqlclient15-dev: Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed E: Broken packages

But I ran this command: sudo apt-cache pkgnames > packages and then checked the packages file and I found the zlib1g-dev package in that list as well as libmysqlclient15-dev

Comment: mysql is installed - but I need mySQLdb, because that is what my script uses.

Comment: Should 'sudo apt-get install mysql' be 'sudo apt-get install mysql-server'?

Comment: Note that for Debian it's `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` and `sudo apt-get install mysql-client`

Comment: And for Fedora, it's `sudo yum install mysql-server` and `sudo yum install mysql-devel`.

Comment: Can we finally admit that 'pip' is a colossal failure? Errors like this are such a pain, and they seem to happen with the majority of packages. Python badly needs a new solution to package management.

Comment: For me on Debian it was libmysqlclient-dev. In fact I have installed both libmariadbclient-dev libmysqlclient-dev

Comment: Solved my problem on Debian 10 with python 3.7.3

Comment: This comment is a copy of a github thread. Please consider adding the reference

Comment: You really don't need mysql-server itself, just client-dev.

Comment: And for fedora using dnf, use `dnf install -y community-mysql-devel`. Use `dnf provides mysql_config` to find out which packages have this file generally.

Comment: Worked for me, and then I got an error about missing *Python.h*, which I solved installing python3-dev

Comment: For ubunut/debian if not need mysql server just install the libmariadbclient-dev

Comment: For centos 7, it's actually is "yum install mariadb-devel"

Answer (score 230):

I was installing `python-mysql` on Ubuntu 12.04 using

```
pip install mysql-python
```

First I had the same problem:

```
Not Found "mysql_config"
```

This worked for me

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then I had this problem:

```
...
_mysql.c:29:20: error fatal: Python.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio

compilación terminada.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Then I tried with

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

(If you're using python3, install `python3-dev` instead.)

And then I was happy :)

```
pip install mysql-python
    Installing collected packages: mysql-python
      Running setup.py install for mysql-python
        building '_mysql' extension
        gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,4,'beta',4) -D__version__=1.2.4b4 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -g
        In file included from _mysql.c:44:0:
        /usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:422:0: aviso: se redefinió "HAVE_WCSCOLL" [activado por defecto]
        /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:890:0: nota: esta es la ubicación de la definición previa
        gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient_r -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.so
    
Successfully installed mysql-python
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Works too on openSUSE, where "libmysqlclient-dev" becomes "libmysqlclient-devel". Now the pip package installs fine. Thanks.

Comment: installing python dev headers solved the missing Python.h error. Thanks.

Comment: if use python3.x, tried with apt-get install python3-dev.

Comment: This didn't work for me on 14.04 - "E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate"

Comment: This is a good answer, but it is outdated and should be updated. In newer versions of Debian-based Linux apt command will be: `sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev python3-dev`

Answer (score 88):

(Specific to Mac OS X)

I have tried a lot of things, but these set of commands finally worked for me.

1. Install `mysql`

   ```
   brew install mysql
   ```
2. `brew unlink mysql`
3. `brew install mysql-connector-c`
4. Add the mysql bin folder to PATH

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/bin:$PATH
   ```
5. `mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/lib/`
6. Create a symlink

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
   ```
7. `brew reinstall openssl` ([source](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/795#issuecomment-478546366))
8. Finally, install mysql-client

   ```
   LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/ pip install mysqlclient
   ```

Update: 
In case this doesn't work, @vinyll suggests to run `brew link mysql` before step 8.

Comment: For Step 4, use `brew info mysql` to get the actual/correct path to the mysql installation. Then to make the `PATH` change persist, do the `export PATH..` in your ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: step 1-4 with `brew link --overwrite mysql-connector-c` works on my Mac

Comment: Finally, it works on my Catalina. Use specify open ssl is very important.

Comment: You should not need `sudo` to work in /usr/local/Cellar.
`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar…` should be enough.

Comment: I had to do a `brew link mysql` before step 8 to get it running.

Comment: @vinyll it might be the case. The answer was written for *High Sierra*. I no longer am using a mac OS. I'll still add to the updates of the answer, may be it can help someone else.

Comment: if you follows this not work, you might check version of your mysql-connector-c, and change version number in step four to your version.

Comment: Ran only the step 8 after installing `brew install mysql`

Comment: I added these to my `.bashrc`: `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"`
`export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"`, and only ran `brew install mysql`, and it worked. Also fixes all future executions of pip to make sure they use the right ssl libs.

Comment: it was enough for me to just do `brew install mysql`

Answer (score 54):

On Red Hat I had to do

```
sudo yum install mysql-devel gcc gcc-devel python-devel
sudo easy_install mysql-python
```

Then it worked.

Comment: Worked for me on CentOS 7: `yum install MySQL-python`

Comment: If you need to install `MySQL-python` as a Python package, or are using virtualenv, this might help: `yum install mysql-devel; venv/bin/pip install MySQL-python`.

Comment: If you use MariaDB on CentOS 7, run `sudo yum install mariadb-devel` first, then you can install mysqlclient by `pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: where did you get gcc-devel rpm from?

Comment: `yum install mysql-devel` Centos 8

Answer (score 46):

On python 3.5.2 + any future version

`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev python-dev`

Comment: Also the mariadb package worked like a charm : `libmariadb-dev`.

Comment: Perhaps note that `apt-get` is specific to Debian and derived Linux distros like Ubuntu, Mint, etc. This seems to duplicate earlier answers with more details and background.

Answer (score 37):

The below worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev python-dev
```

All though it worked, i still went ahead to do the below:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

Answer (score 28):

I got the same error while trying to install `mysql-python`.

This is how I fixed it.

```
sudo PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin/:$PATH pip install mysql-python
```

The problem was that the installer could not find the mysql_config in the default path. Now it can ..and it worked..

```
 15 warnings generated.
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lm -lmygcc -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_mysql.so -arch x86_64

Successfully installed mysql-python
Cleaning up...
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I was having the same issue installing MySQL locally on a Mac running OSX 10.9.4 (Mavericks). This solution worked for me as well.

Answer (score 25):

I fixed this problem with the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: When running >= Debian Stretch make sure to install `default-libmysqlclient-dev`, since the regular `libmysqlclient-dev` package has no installation candidate.

Answer (score 21):

The commands (mysql too) mPATH might be missing.

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/`

Answer (score 20):

Step1:-**Install Python3 & Python3-dev Both**

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-dev
```

Step2:- **Install Python & Mysql Connector**

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

step3:- **Install python mysql client**

```
sudo apt-get install mysqlclient
```

This will Solve your Problem

Comment: Step 2 fixed this for me.

Comment: This has fixed my issue which had bugged me for 3 hours.. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 19):

The package libmysqlclient-dev is deprecated, so use the below command to fix it.

Package libmysqlclient-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

```
sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 18):

I think the most convenient way to solve this problem in 2020 is using another python package. We don't need install any other binary software.

Try this

`pip install mysql-connector-python`

and then

```html
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
          host="",
          user="",
          passwd="",
          database=""
          )      
cursor = mydb.cursor( buffered=True)
cursor.execute('show tables;')
cursor.execute('insert into test values (null, "a",10)')
mydb.commit()
mydb.disconnect()
```

Comment: More information here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html and here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Answer (score 15):

If you're on macOS and already installed mysql@5.7 via brew install:

1. `brew install mysql-connector-c`
2. `brew unlink mysql@5.7`
3. `brew link --overwrite --dry-run mysql@5.7` first, to see what symlinks are getting overwritten
4. `brew link --overwrite --force mysql@5.7` to actually overwrite mysql-related symlinks with mysql@5.7
5. `pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 12):

I fixed it by installing libmysqlclient:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient16-dev
```

Answer (score 12):

In centos 7 this works for me :

```
yum install mariadb-devel
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: works on rhel8.9

Answer (score 10):

The `MySQL-python` package is using the `mysql_config` command to learn about the `mysql` configuration on your host. Your host does not have the `mysql_config` command.

The MySQL development libraries package (MySQL-devel-xxx) from dev.mysql.com provides this command and the libraries needed by the MySQL-python package. The `MySQL-devel` packages are found in the download - community server area. The MySQL development library package names start with `MySQL-devel` and vary based MySQL version and linux platform (e.g. `MySQL-devel-5.5.24-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm`.)

Note that you do not need to install mysql server.

Answer (score 8):

For Alpine Linux:

`$ apk add mariadb-dev mariadb-client mariadb-libs`

MariaDB is a [drop-in replacement for MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) and became the new standard as of Alpine 3.2. See https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/4264

Comment: which makes my alpine image almost 500MiB, I came to alpine for a smaller image size

Comment: I also have to install python3-dev for the lib to build

Answer (score 7):

On my Fedora 23 machine I had to run the following:

```
sudo dnf install mysql-devel
```

Answer (score 6):

In CentOS 7 , the following things should be done:

```
#step1:install mysql 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/

#step2:
sudo yum install mysql-devel
```

or

```
sudo yum install mysql-community-devel
```

Answer (score 6):

also, i fetch the same problem
[image]
I fixed this problem with the following steps:
First I run this command

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

then I install

```
pip install mysqlclient==2.1.0
```

this is worked for me

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 4):

I think, following lines can be executed on terminal

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql_config /usr/sbin/
```

This mysql_config directory is for zend server on MacOSx. You can do it for linux like following lines

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config /usr/sbin/
```

This is default linux mysql directory.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issues and solved if by adding a symlink to `mysql_config`.

I had installed mysql with homebrew and saw this  in the output.

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
```

Depending on how you got `mysql` it will be in different places.  In my case `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql`
Once you know where it is you should be able to ma a symbolic link to where python is looking for it.  `/usr/local/mysql`

This worked for me.

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/<< VERSION >>/bin/mysql_config   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I solved it by following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-programming-environment-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-server) to install Python with python3-dev on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
```

And now you can set up your virtual environment:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-venv
pyvenv my_env
source my_env/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the python-dev package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

Python 2.5? Sounds like you are using a very old version of Ubuntu Server (Hardy 8.04?) - please confirm which Linux version the server uses.

[python-mysql search on ubuntu package database](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-mysql&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

Some additional info:

From the README of mysql-python -

Red Hat Linux
.............

MySQL-python is pre-packaged in Red Hat Linux 7.x and newer. This
includes Fedora Core and Red Hat Enterprise Linux. You can also
build your own RPM packages as described above.

Debian GNU/Linux
................

Packaged as `python-mysqldb`_::

```
# apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Or use Synaptic.

.. _`python-mysqldb`: http://packages.debian.org/python-mysqldb

Ubuntu
......

Same as with Debian.

Footnote: If you really are using a server distribution older than Ubuntu 10.04 then you are out of official support, and should upgrade sooner rather than later.

Comment: I can confirm for Debian 10
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

Comment: This is all you need to do : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html

Answer (score 2):

This method is only for those who know that Mysql is installed but still mysql_config can't be find. This happens if python install can't find mysql_config in your system path, which mostly happens if you have done the installation via .dmg Mac Package or installed at some custom path. The easiest and documented way by MySqlDB is to change the **site.cfg**. Find the mysql_config which is probably in **/usr/local/mysql/bin/** and change the variable namely **mysql_config** just like below and run the installation again. Don't forget to un-comment it by removing "#"

Change below line

> "#mysql_config = /usr/local/bin/mysql_config"

to

> "mysql_config = /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config"

depending upon the path in your system.

By the way I used python install after changing the **site.cfg**

**sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python setup.py install**

Answer (score 2):

So far, all solutions (Linux) require `sudo` or root rights to install .
Here is a solution if you do not have root rights and without `sudo`. (no `sudo apt install ...`):

1. Download the .deb file of the libmysqlclient-dev, e.g. from [this mirror](http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/MySQL/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/)
2. Navigate to the downloaded file and run `dpkg -x libmysqlclient-dev_<version tag>.deb .` This will extract a folder called `usr`.
3. Symlink `./usr/bin/mysql_config` to somewhere that is found on your `$PATH`:

   `ln -s` `` `pwd` `` `/usr/bin/mysql_config FOLDER_IN_YOUR_PATH`
4. It should now be able to find `mysql_config`

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does this work in CentOS 7? Assuming I dont have root access or dpkg installed , how should I approach it ?

Comment: No need to be root as long as you are working in your own virtual environment

Answer (score 2):

For macOS Mojave , additional configuration was required, for compilers to find **openssl** you may need to set:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS (OS/X) Catalina, I found that I needed to do this:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64/bin/
```

On my computer, the `mysql` command is in `/usr/local/bin` (from the standard MacOS installer, not "brew").

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, just added the path where *mysql_config* resided to the environment variable PATH and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get build-dep python-mysqldb` will install all the dependencies to build the package from PIP/easy_install

Answer (score 1):

As actual error is

```
gcc ... -I/usr/include/python2.7 ...

_mysql.c:29:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

and If you can't install python-dev or python-devel packages, you may download archive with needed version of python sources from http://hg.python.org/ and place headers files in proper folder for include

Answer (score 1):

Just type:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
$ venv/bin/pip install MySQL-python
```

This will solve this problems.

Comment: If you get an error with mysql_config, istall this: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS 7 instead of `yum install mysql-devel` do `yum install mysql-community-devel`

This does not require you to add the mysql repo.

Comment: No package mysql-community-devel available.

Answer (score 1):

Debian 11 install libmariadb-dev-compat to provide mysql_config binary for pip install mysqlclient

Answer (score -2):

sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install MySQL-python

NOtice you should install python-dev as well, the packages like MySQL-python are compiled from source. The pythonx.x-dev packages contain the necessary header files for linking against python. [Why does installing numpy require python-dev in Kubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073695/why-does-installing-numpy-require-python-dev-in-kubuntu-12-04)