# Why does installing numpy require python-dev in Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian, pip

Just starting out in python on a pendrive 12.04 Kubuntu environment.  I had to install GCC (understand that), but I also had to install python-dev before I could use PIP to install numpy.  Why do I need python-dev?

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install pip
cd /usr/lib/python2.7/
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo pip install numpy
```

Comment: why does anything matter?  As I said I am new to the language and wanted to know so that in the future I understand why I need what.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `pip` to install numpy, the packages is compiled from source. The `pythonx.x-dev` packages contain the necessary header files for linking against python.