# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-module, pyopenssl

I'm trying to install `pyopenssl v 0.13.1` on my kali linux distro.

when I do:

```
sudo pip install pyopenssl==0.13.1

Downloading/unpacking pyopenssl==0.13.1
  Downloading pyOpenSSL-0.13.1.tar.gz (254kB): 254kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pyopenssl/setup.py) egg_info for package pyopenssl
```

....

it returns this error:

```
----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of pyOpenSSL
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pyopenssl/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-EElRHo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pyopenssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What can i try now?

thanks!

Comment: what does `locale ` output from bash?

Comment: root@kali:/# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: do you get the same error using pyopenssl==0.14

Comment: no, a different one:
http://pastebin.com/P5aBpNz1

Comment: I need it for an external program. I tried to install 0.12, 0.10, 0.9, 0.8 but with no success, btw.

Comment: not  sure if it is important but what version of openssl do you have

Comment: why your `LC_ALL=` and `LANGUAGE=` is not set?

Comment: root@kali:~# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

Comment: I set LC_ALL and LANGUAGE too:
root@kali:~# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced almost identical errors while trying to install the leveldb package, and the numpy package--this doesn't just seem to be a problem with pyOpenSSL.

I was able to fix it by installing the `python-devel` package on Fedora 20.  According to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073695) question, the python headers are necessary to install packages using the `pip` tool (at least this seems to be the case for many packages).

Since Kali seems to be a Debian-based distro, the name of the package you'll want is `python-dev`.

---

Let me know if this works.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers, right now I haven't my distro up and running, I will try ASAP!

Comment: I can confirm that adding `python-devel` helps when installing `numpy`. On Ubuntu it would be `python-dev` package