# Installing MySQL-python for Django

Tags: django, virtualenv, mysql-python

I've just learned how to use `virtualenv` and I installed Django 1.4.5. I'm assuming that the `virtualenv` created a clean slate for me to work on so with the Django 1.4.5 installed, I copied all my previous files into the `virtualenv` environment.

I tried to run the server but I get an error saying `"no module named MySQLdb"`. I think this means that I forgot to install MySQL-python. I tried to install it via

```
    pip install MySQL-python
```

But I get this error

```
    Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
    Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
    The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,
    and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
    install a more recent version first, using
    'easy_install -U distribute'.

    (Currently using distribute 0.6.24     (/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg))
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,

    and can't be installed while this script is running. Please

    install a more recent version first, using

    'easy_install -U distribute'.



    (Currently using distribute 0.6.24  (/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg))

    ----------------------------------------
    Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 2 in /home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.4.5/build/MySQL-python
```

Not quite sure how to go about fixing this problem =/ any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I recently had exactly this issue (just not in relation to Django). In my case I am developing on Ubuntu 12.04 using the default pip and distribute versions, which are basically a little out of date for `MySQL-python`.

Because you are working in an isolated virtualenv, you can safely follow the suggested instruction without affecting your Python installation.

So you can...

```
workon your_virtualenv #activate your virtualenv, you do use virtualenvwrapper, right?
easy_install -U distribute #update distribute on your virtualenv
pip install MySQL-python #install your package
```

If for some reason upgrading distribute is not an option, you could try installing an older version of `MySQL-python` as follows (you'd have to check this version is compatible with your version of Django):

```
pip install MySQL-python==x.y.z #where x.y.z is the version you want
```

Comment: AWESOME! thank you sooo much! the easy_install -U distribute did the trick! thanks!!!

Comment: no probs, first time I've been able to answer an SO question of the kind I so often ask :)

Comment: I have yet to answer one =/

Comment: note that distribute has been remerged with setuptools, so this answer may no longer apply (there may be a better way to update setuptools/distribute, or create the virtualenv using a more recent version of virtualenv itself)

Answer (score 14):

Spent an hour looking through stackoverflow. Evntually found answer [in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface). This is what saved me:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

mysql_config goes with the package.

Answer (score 8):

When doing in a virtualenv :

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

I got

```
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

To install mysql_config, as Artem Fedosov said, first install

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

then everything works fine in virtualenv

Comment: This is the best answer for me, I was running into the `mysql_config` error with the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

MySQL driver for Python (mysql-python) needs libmysqlclient-dev. You can get it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

If python-dev is not installed, you may have to install it too:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Now you can install MySQL driver:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

**Here is a more detailed documentation for MySQL in Django:**

http://codex.themedelta.com/how-to-install-django-with-mysql-in-a-virtualenv-on-linux/

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

inside the virtualenv

Answer (score 2):

The commands are always run in ubuntu:

```
easy_install -U distribute
```

later

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and finally

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 2):

The suggested solutions didn't work out for me, because I still got compilation errors after running

```
`$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`
```

so I had to run

```
 apt-get install python-dev
```

Then everything worked fine for me with

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Version Python 2.7**

**MySQL-python** package, you should use either MySQL_python‑1.2.5‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl or
MySQL_python‑1.2.5‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl depending on whether you have installed 32-bit or 64-bit Python.

```
pip install MySQL_python‑1.2.5‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl
```

if you are using **mysqlclient** package, then use
mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl or
mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

```
pip install mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
```

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient