# django and mysql_config error

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

I tried to install mysql module with `pip install mysql-python` and I got this:

```
    (env)nathann@esp2:/home/esp2$ sudo pip install mysql-python
Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108Kb): 108Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mysql-python

Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -g
    _mysql.c:29:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/esp2/build/mysql-python/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-yuSaAG-record/install-record.txt:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -g

_mysql.c:29:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/esp2/build/mysql-python/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-yuSaAG-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/nathann/.pip/pip.log
(env)nathann@esp2:/home/esp2$
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not have the python development headers installed. On debian flavors:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

On other unix flavors, sometimes it's called `python-devel`

Comment: I had to scratch my virtualenv and start over and install mysql and everything again. this time it worked. :D