# mysql_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface for mariadb 10 Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python, mariadb

After I installed Mariadb 10 the Mysql workbench and JPDB client both connect and work fine so next step was get programming with Python (using SQLAlchemy) which seems to require MySQL-python so I went to update that and got:
"mysql_config not found" I looked in the "usual places" and did not see a file...

So I followed some ideas from an [earlier question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)
and tried to install: apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

which got me to:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.2) but 10.0.10+maria-1~saucy is to be installed

which kind of hits a brick wall for me

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Found it! The case is that mariadb has a compatible package, if you have the ppa setup as in http://downloads.mariadb.org/. Just

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

Thanks to http://data-matters.blogspot.com/2013/08/install-mysql-python-with-mariadb.html 
After this the `mysql-python` installs correctly

Comment: This is a solution to install libraries depend on mysql-dev on ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: You can also just install 'libmariadbclient-dev' from Ubuntu, without the need for the custom ppa.

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 18.04, however for Mac Mojave I had to do `brew install mysql-connector-c`

Answer (score 39):

For Centos 7.0 install the following:

```
yum install mariadb-devel
```

For Fedora 23+:

```
dnf install mariadb-devel
```

Comment: the question pertains to Ubuntu, not Centos 7.0.

Comment: @drs Never the less this answer is useful as this question shows up for generic linux searches

Comment: Why does a package by the name mariadb-devel contain mysql development libraries?

Answer (score 22):

There's NO solution on Ubuntu 16.04

Doing:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/mariadb_config /usr/bin/mysql_config
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Best answer for Ubuntu 16.04 !

Comment: This fixed the same issue on debian buster

Answer (score 9):

Install the following library:

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev
```

And create a symbolic link named `mysql_config`:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/mariadb_config /usr/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: This was it. Something is rotten in the state of ubuntu 16

Answer (score 7):

For Debian/Ubuntu PPA from https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/

for MariaDB 10.1: `apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev`
for MariaDB 10.2: `apt-get install libmariadb-dev`
for MariaDB 10.3: `apt-get install libmariadb-dev-compat`

Comment: Thanks! This one is really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 17.04 the following worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Worked for me on debian as well

Answer (score 2):

For Debian Jessie:

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev 
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/mariadb_config /usr/bin/mysql_config
```