# Problem with installing mariadb using pip install

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, mariadb

I'm writing a discord bot in python and I want to host it on my vps using pterodactyl.
The only problem is that I can't run the `mariadb` module.

When installing `mariadb~=1.0.9` from requirements.txt, I get this error in the console:

```py
Collecting mariadb~=1.0.9
  Using cached mariadb-1.0.9.zip (85 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5af1rjco/mariadb_79202a8d2ec6465081f14415b6232796/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5af1rjco/mariadb_79202a8d2ec6465081f14415b6232796/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-t7yd4lwb
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5af1rjco/mariadb_79202a8d2ec6465081f14415b6232796/
    Complete output (17 lines):
    /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-5af1rjco/mariadb_79202a8d2ec6465081f14415b6232796/setup.py", line 26, in <module>
        cfg = get_config(options)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-5af1rjco/mariadb_79202a8d2ec6465081f14415b6232796/mariadb_posix.py", line 59, in get_config
        cc_version = mariadb_config(config_prg, "cc_version")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-5af1rjco/mariadb_79202a8d2ec6465081f14415b6232796/mariadb_posix.py", line 28, in mariadb_config
        raise EnvironmentError(
    OSError: mariadb_config not found.
    
    Please make sure, that MariaDB Connector/C is installed on your system.
    Either set the environment variable MARIADB_CONFIG or edit the configuration
    file 'site.cfg' and set the 'mariadb_config option, which should point
    to the mariadb_config utility.
    The MariaDB Download website at <https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/c/>
    provides latest stable releease of Connector/C.
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/b0/0fa0bf67c347464e04c970e406e6d4b0eea0b76c9aff6111c85708950cfc/mariadb-1.0.9.zip#sha256=02a9b3d0a076e9a0d0ea1c48b45ed09b6475e2b6a4e8c81ed9f1e82caf3bfc29 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mariadb/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mariadb~=1.0.9 (from versions: 0.9.52, 0.9.53, 0.9.54, 0.9.55, 0.9.56, 0.9.57, 0.9.58, 0.9.59, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.1.0a1, 1.1.0b1, 1.1.0b2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mariadb~=1.0.9
```

I looked at other similar questions and installed:

MariaDB Connector/C, which is a dependency.

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev
```

PIP to install MariaDB Connector/Python.

```
pip3 install mariadb
```

As I watched, `mariadb` installed in my folder:
`/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages`, but in the discord-bot server location in the `/var/lib/pterodactyl/volumes/0a4e3290-1f7f-4b2a-8754-02402baef643/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages` `mariadb` module is missing

I've tried solutions with these answers but nothing

[Problem with pip install mariadb - mariadb_config not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63027020/problem-with-pip-install-mariadb-mariadb-config-not-found)
[Python MariaDB pip install failed, missing mariadb_config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584959/python-mariadb-pip-install-failed-missing-mariadb-config)
[mysql_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface for mariadb 10 Ubuntu 13.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949654/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface-for-mariadb-10-u)

ubuntu version 20.04

Comment: [libmariadb-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libmariadb-dev/filelist) does include `mariadb_config`. I tried installing the packages stated in a container and `pip3 install mariadb` and this worked without error. Verify `dpkg -L libmariadb-dev` shows `mariadb_config`, you can run `mariadb_config` separately.

Comment: I already have installed mariadb in my .local folder, but i still get error: `File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mariadb/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>from ._mariadb import (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mariadb._mariadb'`

Comment: Got this problem on rapberry pi os, but there it worked with "apt install libmariadb-dev", however it did not install the latest version. So your problem may be a to old version of mariadb. (But since this is a guess, I did not put this as a answer).

Answer (score 0):

If using Redhat, just `yum install python3-pymysql` and `python3 -m pip install pymysql`.
For some reason rhel 8 does not have the right mariadb connector version and so latest mariadb pip package cannot be installed.