# Populate a dictionary with the result of a query

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm currently doing this:

```
    cursor.execute('SELECT thing_id, thing_name FROM things')
    things = [];
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        things.append(dict([('thing_id',row[0]),
                             ('thing_name',row[1])
                             ]))
```

Is there some shorthand I can use to do this, or should I write a little helper function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
things = [{'thing_id': row[0], 'thing_name': row[1]} for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

or using list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
things = [dict(zip(['thing_id', 'thing_name'], row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

If you use [`Cursor.description` attribute](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description), you can get column names:

```
names = [d.name for d in c.description]
things = [dict(zip(names, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I've gone with your second code block and specifically articulated column names in my select statement.

Comment: @Drewdin, What `dict` do you mean?

Comment: @falsetru I wanted to get just the dict, things = {'stuff':1}, without it being inside of the list. things = [{'stuff':1}]. I guess its required because it a list comprehension? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor-class.html) class instead of [`MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor-class.html) by passing cursor class to [`cursor`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.connections.Connection-class.html#cursor) method:

```
In [9]: cur = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

In [10]: cur.execute('SELECT * FROM test_table')
Out[10]: 3L

In [11]: cur.fetchall()
Out[11]: 
({'create_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 2, 10, 22, 23),
  'id': 1L,
  'name': 'Bob'},
 {'create_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 2, 10, 22, 34),
  'id': 2L,
  'name': 'Stive'},
 {'create_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 2, 10, 22, 37),
  'id': 3L,
  'name': 'Alex'})
```

Comment: Interesting approach - ta!

Comment: I've tried this but each time I get "ImportError: No module named mysqldb
". Running Debain Stretch.  I installed "sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb". Tried this but got install errors "    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last): …"

Comment: Have you tried this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface

Comment: Still struggling.  I have followed the comments/answers and have done or repeated them.  My program throws the error on the "import mysqldb" line.  Except for that the code is working fine, I just wanted to try your DictCursor idea.

Comment: Spoke too soon.  The code works but I don't get the dictionary object from the fetchall method.

Comment: I think it might be better to ask another question, it is hard to say what's wrong without actual code