# MySQL: pymysql or mysqldb to access a dictionary cursor functionality

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I would like to get a dictionary object as the result of an "execute("insert...") " SQL command in Python 2.7 using Debain Stretch on a Raspberry Pi V3.  The normal object is a tuple so elements are accessed via an integer index. From the web it would appear that two libraries will supply that discionary functionality: mysqldb and pymysql.  When I use "import mysqldb" I get an error "ImportError: No module named mysqldb". If I use "import pymysql" I don't get any errors but the result is a tuple and not a dictionary, which is also what I would get it I just take the default cursor.  If I modify my code to specify the column name, ie

> print("row ", mycursor.rowcount, "id ", x['id'], " date ", x['date_time'])

Then I get an error about using a non-interger index. 
Here is example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pymysql
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="xxx",
  passwd="yyy",
  database="zzz")
print(db)
mycursor = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
#    mycursor = db.cursor()
mycursor.execute("select * from table;")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
    print("row ", mycursor.rowcount, "id ", x[0], " date ", x[1])
# if I use "print("row ", mycursor.rowcount, "id ", x["id"], " date ", x[date_Time])" it throws an error
```

This is a fresh install of Stretch on an Raspberry Pi v3.  I have installed the following:

- sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
- sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
- sudo apt-get -y install python-mysql.connector
- sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
- sudo pip install PyMySQL

I have search the web for answers, including the two references below

But so far have not found a solution.  Can anyone assist?....RDK

Comment: The references did not come through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034943/populate-a-dictionary-with-the-result-of-a-query and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface

Comment: One of the references suggested that I add "/usr/local/mysql/bin/" to my path, but that folder does not exist on this MariaDB Debian setup.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `pymysql.connect` instead of `mysql.connector.connect`

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="xxx",
    passwd="yyy",
    database="zzz")
print(db)
mycursor = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
mycursor.execute("select * from table;")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
    print("row ", mycursor.rowcount, "id ", x["id"], " date ", x["date_Time"])
```

Comment: Thanks,, but it throws this error"  File "/mnt/usbdrive/pgms/modbus/sqltest.py", line 24, in <module>
    print("row ", mycursor.rowcount, "id ", x['id'], " date ", x['daate_time'])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
"

Comment: Not sure what I did or what I changed but now before by your changes do work.

Comment: However, when I now do an mycursor.execute("insert into …  ) I get this message, but the data seems to have been inserted ok. "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:329: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'ArrayV' at row 1")   self._do_get_result()".  Any ideas why? That same statement does not generate those message when I'm not referencing pymysql in the connect or cursor statements.

Answer (score 0):

Howie Peng answered the part of my question relating to using pymysql to get access to a DictCursor. Thanks.

Now, I have figured out the issues with using mysqldb!!  The first answer is that it is not ***mysqldb*** but rather ***MySQLdb***, note upper and lower case!!  That change allowed my Python program get past the import statement but it still failed for the `db = MySQLdb.connect(...` statement.  It seems, that unlike mysql.connector and pymysql, MySQLdb uses ***db*** instead of ***database*** to specify the database name.

Don't you love it?....RDK