# MYSQL- python pip install error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I tried to get build an app on Django and I wanted to use MySQL as the database. After setting up the settings.py right, I tried to migrate. Then I got the obvious error saying that MySQL is not installed. So inorder to install MySQL, I ran:

```
sudo -H pip install MySQL-python
```

I get the following error:

```
    Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-zAMhWo/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-zAMhWo/MySQL-python/
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**MySQL-python**

> MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.4 through 2.7 are currently
>   supported. Python-3.0 will be supported in a future release.

You can install mysqlclient or pymysql,I prefer the latter:

```
pip install pymysql
```

And add this to your  `manage.py`:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Comment: sudo and your command worked. But I cannot still run python manage.py migrate.

Comment: @GeethW  add this to your `manage.py`,`import pymysql`
`pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()`

Comment: Thank you so much McGrady. I don't really understand what happened. Can you explain? I tried so many driver options. For example, pip install mysql-python and then manually downloading a .dmg from oracle. Nothing worked. Please explain.

Comment: @GeethW Actually,I can't explain what happened when you install mysql-python, it seems that `pymysql` is more friendly than `mysql-python` to support python now.

Answer (score 6):

Did you install the SQL client dev pacakge on your system?

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

if you are using mariadb, the drop in replacement for mysql, then run

```
sudo apt install libmariadbclient-dev
```

then try again

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

Answer (score 2):

Installations of `mysql` in some environments can place binaries in directory relative to environment. `pip` installation fails because `setup.py` does not find `mysql_config` at expected path. Steps for source installation -

1. Download files [here](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/#files) Edit `mysql_config` path mentioned in
   `MySQL-python-1.2.5/site.cfg` with correct path on your local
   environment. For example,

```
mysql_config = /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

2. Run below commands inside directory `MySQL-python-1.2.5` -

```
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing a MySQL db driver?

The following documentation tells you how to install one:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem trying to install **mysqlclient**, try to install **mysql-devel**. on RHEL/Centos for example:

> yum install mysql-devel