# "pip install MySQL-python" not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, mysql-python, failed-installation

When I try to install MySQL-python using pip for Python 2.7, it is not working anymore on Ubuntu 20.04 - on Ubuntu 18.04 it still works...

Any idea of how I could make this run on Ubuntu 20.04?

I know that Python 2.7 is not supported anymore, but I do still need to run it on my Ubuntu 20.04 server as I am running an older version of [Trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/) which I can't upgrade right now because of plugins that are not working in the latest version...

```
root@andreas-VirtualBox:/home/andreas# pip install MySQL-python
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Building wheel for MySQL-python (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python2 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-aBO5pH/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-aBO5pH/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-tWAoxI
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-aBO5pH/mysql-python/
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-QDqKfA/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
  _mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
     44 | #include "my_config.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
  Running setup.py clean for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
    Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python2 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-aBO5pH/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-aBO5pH/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-K48jZF/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python2.7/MySQL-python
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-aBO5pH/mysql-python/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-QDqKfA/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
       44 | #include "my_config.h"
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python2 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-aBO5pH/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-aBO5pH/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-K48jZF/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python2.7/MySQL-python Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Do you have the mysql development files installed? Try `apt-get install mysql-devel`, then attempt to install MySQL-Python.

Comment: The package mysql-devel doesn't exist in Ubuntu 20.04 (neither does mysql-dev), but libmysqlclient-dev was already installed when I tried to "pip install MySQL-python"

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244866/mysqldb-install-error-mysql-c4423-error-my-config-h-no-such-file-or-dire/60828499#60828499

Comment: Thanks - this helped me to install MySQL-python!

Comment: I do now get the following error when opening Trac: "ERROR: can't retrieve session: TimeoutError: Unable to get database connection within 0 seconds. (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect')"
Do you have an idea of how to solve this? There is probably also something missing in Ubuntu 20.04, as for Ubuntu 18.04 it works with the same setup and MySQL-python installed...

Comment: this is a different issue. Please post it in another question with an appropriate title so that it is searchable by users. Also, post the entire stack trace and tag me in the comments of the new question and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230113/discussion-between-andreas-and-michael-ruth).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087499/failing-to-install-mysql-python