# Django over Docker does not install mysqlclient

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I want to integrate MySQL with Django, MySQL is running over Docker and I put the config like this to connect to the db docker with Django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'restaurant',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'default-character-set': 'utf8',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET default_storage_engine=INNODB',
        }
    }
}
```

But when Django is trying to connect to the mysql db, it throws me this error:

[image]

I tried to install mysqlclient with pip, but I have this error:

[image]

These are the [docker-compose.dev.yml](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/Restaurant/blob/master/docker-compose.dev.yml) and [Dockerfile](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/Restaurant/blob/master/Dockerfile) configs.

If someone needs the complete code, [here](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/Restaurant) you can find it, and test it with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build`.

Thanks :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)

Comment: Just in case that comment was too cryptic, the issue is that to install `mysqlclient` on alpine, you also have to install the native mysql libraries.  The referenced answer contains instructions for how to use apk to install the mysql client libraries you'll need to install `mysqlclient`.  Alternatively, you can switch your config over to use mysql-connector-python, which does not need the native libraries installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mysqlclient has native dependencies that must be installed before you can `pip install` it.  When running in docker, and especially in alpine, you probably want to switch over to using `mysql-connector-python` which is a pure python library that does not have any native dependencies l,ike mysqlclient.  Update your requirements file and update your settings to use `mysql.connector.django` if you want to use `mysql-connector-python`.

Comment: I could resolve it running in the dockerfile:

`RUN apk add --no-cache bash mariadb-dev mariadb-client mariadb-libs python3-dev build-base`

But I'm going to try `mysql-connector-python`, but for more complex queries or to have a better performance, I need to install `mysqlclient`? or with `mysql-connect-python` is ok?

Comment: native will always have better performance.  Complex queries will run just as slow in mysqlclient as in mysql-connector-python.  Biggest performance increase is for large queries because native string processing is much faster than python string processing.  But, I;ve only noticed a 2-5% dropoff in performance using mysql-connector-python.

Answer (score 0):

Another response would be adding:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache bash mariadb-dev mariadb-client mariadb-libs python3-dev build-base
```

On the dockerfile.

Comment: have the same problem. I put this line into my dockerfile but error occured:

`ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  mariadb-libs (missing):
    required by: world[mariadb-libs]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache bash mariadb-dev mariadb-client mariadb-libs python3-dev build-base' returned a non-zero code: 1`