# ImportError: No module named MySQLdb Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

I can't install anything to fix it. I tried out the following commands.

```
pip install MySQL-python when I run this please see the screen shot in error
```

> pip install mysqlclient brew install mysql brew install
>   libmysqlclient-dev

```
more pictures [![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][1]][1]



  PASML-1717136:server $ Python2.7 main.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 68, in <module>
        HANDLER = get_handlers()
      File "main.py", line 59, in get_handlers
        adapter = MysqlAdapter(CONFIG.DB_CONN)
      File "/Users/mnaeem668/Projects/Automation_KPI/server/../server/adapters/mysql_adapter.py", line 24, in __init__
        self._connect()
      File "/Users/mnaeem668/Projects/Automation_KPI/server/../server/adapters/mysql_adapter.py", line 33, in _connect
        self.engine = create_engine(conn_str)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
        return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87, in create
        dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
        return __import__("MySQLdb")
    ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
    Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'" in <bound method MysqlAdapter.__del__ of <server.adapters.mysql_adapter.MysqlAdapter object at 0x11240cb50>> ignored
```

**Update: install python-MySQLdb**

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-MySQLdb (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-MySQLdb
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are attempting to install python-mysql without having mysql and its dependencies installed on your machine.
From your screenshots it appears that you are running on MacOS.
Please take a look at the following comment:

> mySQLdb is a python interface for mysql, but it is not mysql itself. And apparently mySQLdb needs the command 'mysql_config', so you need to install that first.
>
> Can you confirm that you did or did not install mysql itself, by running "mysql" from the shell? That should give you a response other than "mysql: command not found".

And view the following comment on installation on MacOS
[mysql_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51149263/12591770)