# Cannot connect to a mysql:// instance with SQLAlchemy from my Mac

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, pip

I'm trying to connect to a mySQL database through SQLAlchemy and I can't get it to work for the life of me. Here's the code I'm running and the error I'm getting.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import sqlalchemy as sql
 import urllib.parse
 user = 'user'
 pswd = urllib.parse.quote_plus('password')
 connect_string = 'mysql://{}:{}@localhost:8018/test'.format(user, pswd)
 sql_engine = sql.create_engine(connect_string)

 >>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

After seeing this, I've tried numerous different ways of installing 'MySQLdb' ( including the obvious 'pip3 install mysqlclient') and when I run that in my terminal, I get the following.

```
 >>> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I know this question has been posted here before but I've spent 2 hours now trying to figure this out with the advice on those other questions and nothing is working. Can anyone help? Below is a picture of the full error I'm getting when I try and install "mysqlclient"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to

https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/#files

mysqlclient only offers pre-compiled wheel files for Windows machines running 64-bit Python 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8. All other configurations require that it be installed from source, and that can be ... complicated.

You may want to try installing [PyMySQL](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/) instead, and use a connection URI of the form

```
mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@<host>/<dbname>[?<options>]
```

Answer (score 1):

`SQLAlchemy` is a high-level [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). To connect to backends it needs [Python DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) driver(s). You can install SQLAlchemy with a MySQL driver using

```
pip install -U 'SQLAlchemy[mysql]'
```

See [the list of extra drivers](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/60e7034a7423955cd89d5624f8769d3804ca6d82/setup.py#L165) available for such installation.

Most drivers have parts written in C/C++ and thus require compilation. You need to [install MySQL-related libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7475223/7976758) to compile `mysqlclient`. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+%5Bmysql%5D+%22mysql_config%22+not+found

There are a few pure-Python drivers. They're easier to install. PyMySQL is one such driver. To install it along with SQLAlchemy:

```
pip install -U 'SQLAlchemy[pymysql]'
```