# mysqlclient install in python3 on mac os

Tags: django, python-3.7

install mysqlclient in python3 system this error

command `pip3 install mysqlclient`

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-abwz3tky/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-abwz3tky/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-abwz3tky/mysqlclient/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-abwz3tky/mysqlclient/
Complete output (12 lines):
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
/bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-abwz3tky/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-abwz3tky/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 61, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs")
  File "/private/var/folders/tj/vjwl0qpd6l5ct6bdjgwyk1rh0000gp/T/pip-install-abwz3tky/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
OSError: mysql_config not found
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql\_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)

Answer (score 7):

Did you install required prerequisites for [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python#install)?

> macOS (Homebrew)
>
> Install MySQL and mysqlclient:
>
> #### Assume you are activating Python 3 venv
>
> $ brew install mysql
>
> $ pip install mysqlclient
>
> If you don't want to install MySQL server, you can use mysql-client instead:
>
> #### Assume you are activating Python 3 venv
>
> $ brew install mysql-client
>
> $ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
>
> $ export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"
>
> $ pip install mysqlclient