# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. I try to install mysqlclient in fedora

Tags: python, mysql, django, linux, fedora

I want to connect mysql to my django project

I try to install mysqlclient and got error I use Linux fedora os and I want to connect myq to my django project for which I have to install mysqlclient I run command **pip install mysqlclient** ,then try **pip install mysqlclient==1.3.12** I also try that commands in virtual env and got the same error I installed python-devel by using **yum install python3-devel** inside root after that i try for installing libmysqlclient by using **yum install  mysql-devel** i gives me an error and then I try **dnf install libmysqlclient-dev** got the error
[after running pip install mysqlclient i got this error shown in image in the link below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9KuU.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql\_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)

Comment: have you install the mysql-server in your os. most probably this is the case.