# Error while trying to pip install mysqlclient in my django project?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, pip, virtualenv

This is the traceback when running `pip install mysqlclient`. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

    cwd: /tmp/pip-install-0w18_khs/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-0w18_khs/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-0w18_khs/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 65, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-0w18_khs/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
        raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: It could be a duplicate question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql\_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)