# mysql_config_path not found Ubuntu 18.04 distro in WSL2

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, wsl-2

Please can anyone help me to resolve this error? I've tried solutions suggested online and on stackoverflow but the error is still there.

I have this package in my requirements.txt file - mysqlclient==2.0.1
when I run my docker-compose file it gives this error

```
Collecting mysqlclient==2.0.1
Downloading mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz (87 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:   
/bin/sh: mysql_config: not found
/bin/sh: mariadb_config: not found
/bin/sh: mysql_config: not found
raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
OSError: mysql_config not found
```

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on WSL2 for my project.
Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I'll answer it since it's the only one that shows up in search.

Use `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev python-dev`. I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface).