# unable to install mysqlclient interface on python3.6

Tags: python, centos, mysql-connector

I am trying to install `mysqlclient` package using `pip install mysqlclient` but keep getting this error as

`OSError: mysql_config not found`

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz (88 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/airflow_env/bin/python3.6 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dfln7is0/mysqlclient_696dd7cf04d147ed91836f80c68bc64c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dfln7is0/mysqlclient_696dd7cf04d147ed91836f80c68bc64c/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-l5usa3c5
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-dfln7is0/mysqlclient_696dd7cf04d147ed91836f80c68bc64c/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    mysql_config --version
    mariadb_config --version
    mysql_config --libs
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-dfln7is0/mysqlclient_696dd7cf04d147ed91836f80c68bc64c/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-dfln7is0/mysqlclient_696dd7cf04d147ed91836f80c68bc64c/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-dfln7is0/mysqlclient_696dd7cf04d147ed91836f80c68bc64c/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
        raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried:

- upgrading setuptools: `pip install --upgrade setuptools`,
- installing `python-devel`, `python3-devel`, `mysql-devel`
- installing mariadb: `yum install mariadb-devel` gives error

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-devel.x86_64 1:5.5.68-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.68-1.el7 for package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.68-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.68-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.68-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-21.el7_9 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: zlib-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: krb5-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package krb5-devel.x86_64 0:1.15.1-50.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libkadm5(x86-64) = 1.15.1-50.el7 for package: krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libverto-devel for package: krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux-devel for package: krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcom_err-devel for package: krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: keyutils-libs-devel for package: krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.x86_64
---> Package zlib-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.7-18.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package keyutils-libs-devel.x86_64 0:1.5.8-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package libcom_err-devel.x86_64 0:1.42.9-19.el7 will be installed
---> Package libkadm5.x86_64 0:1.15.1-50.el7 will be installed
---> Package libselinux-devel.x86_64 0:2.5-15.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol-devel(x86-64) >= 2.5-10 for package: libselinux-devel-2.5-15.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(libsepol) for package: libselinux-devel-2.5-15.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(libpcre) for package: libselinux-devel-2.5-15.el7.x86_64
---> Package libverto-devel.x86_64 0:0.2.5-4.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libsepol-devel.x86_64 0:2.5-10.el7 will be installed
---> Package pcre-devel.x86_64 0:8.32-17.el7 will be installed
Removing mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.68-1.el7 - u due to obsoletes from installed mysql-community-libs-8.0.22-1.el7.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.68-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.68-1.el7 for package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.68-1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.68-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.68-1.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am using centos7:
`CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`

I tried this using docker container in centos7 and did not face any issue.

Comment: [mysql_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql\_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)

Comment: I am afraid, this did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

As @Luuk stated inside the comments you are trying to install an interface to mysql with your pip command rather than sql itself. That is why you are getting the following `OSError`

```
>>> OSError: mysql_config not found
```

First you should install mariadb as explained in their [webpage](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/installing-mariadb-10-on-centos-7-rhel-7/) that is

```
$ sudo yum install mariadb-server
```

and afterwards run the set of commands

```
$ sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

Also note that everything runs correctly inside your docker container because it acts like a separate machine.

Comment: Yeah, you should have flagged it as a duplicate, rather than answering it again.

Comment: I tried installing mariadb-server and python3-devel, as you mentioned, but I am still facing same problem while installing `mysql-devel`:
```Error: Package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.68-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.68-1.el7```