# pip install mysqlclient returns OSError: mysql_config not found on CentOS9 with Python3.9

Tags: python, libmysqlclient

I'm currently setting-up an existing Django project using a virtual environment with Python3.9 on my CentOS system.
When I ran the `pip install requirements.txt` command it gets stuck on installing mysqlclient and shows an error: `OSError: mysql_config not found`.

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: /home/test/Projects/env/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-of5a4s4j/mysqlclient_d1bfd0ee1acb4132874cf63635277f3e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-of5a4s4j/mysqlclient_d1bfd0ee1acb4132874cf63635277f3e/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-0xsnkncd
        cwd: /tmp/pip-install-of5a4s4j/mysqlclient_d1bfd0ee1acb4132874cf63635277f3e/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    /bin/sh: line 1: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-of5a4s4j/mysqlclient_d1bfd0ee1acb4132874cf63635277f3e/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-of5a4s4j/mysqlclient_d1bfd0ee1acb4132874cf63635277f3e/setup_posix.py", line 47, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
    File "/tmp/pip-install-of5a4s4j/mysqlclient_d1bfd0ee1acb4132874cf63635277f3e/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
```

I also tried installing the required prerequisites for as mentioned in https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

`dnf install python3-devel` command and other requirements such as `gcc` works fine but it shows an Error for
`dnf install mysql-devel`

The error shows:

```
No match for argument: mysql-devel
Error: Unable to find a match: mysql-devel
```

So far, I tried the following commands:

```
dnf install mysql-devel
dnf install mysql-community-devel
dnf install mariadb-devel
dnf install libmysqlclient-dev
dnf install libmariadbclient-dev
```

But no luck.

dnf install mysql-server
is already installed

Just for the record, I have tried all the answers from other posts but almost all of their answers were

```
  yum install python-devel mysql-devel
```

which was not working for me.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7475296/11286032

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. 
I've already installed `mysql-server` but `libmysqlclient-dev` and `libmariadbclient-dev` packages are not found

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) Low-contrast images are particularly pesky for some users with disabilities.

Comment: Hello, I removed my image

Comment: The fact that the answers there do not help for current CentOS do not change the fact that the question has been asked and answered many times. It explains what's wrong and how to troubleshoot the situation. If you solve it for CentOS 9, probably add an answer to the old question and accept the duplicate nomination.

Comment: Your image seemed to contain more information, where it tried to install multiple packages before concluding that none of them were available. Or do I misremember?

Comment: Hello, the current traceback code is the image that I posted before

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/yum/ has some tips for various RedHat-based distros. https://centos.pkgs.org/9-stream/centos-crb-x86_64/mariadb-devel-10.5.12-3.el9.x86_64.rpm.html seems to indicate that mariadb-devel should be available for CentOS 9 from the standard repositories, though I'm not familiar enough with CentOS to decode all the acronyms there (perhaps CRB is something you can or cannot use, for example?)

Comment: Hello, yes you are correct. I was able to solve it. I think the problem is that `mysql-devel ` is no longer supported on the newer versions of CentOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it by checking all the packages that CentOS provides by using `dnf provides mysql_config`

It will list all the available packages that provides mysql_config. When I did this there were 4 results shown

```
mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.1.13-3.el9.i686 : Development files for mariadb-connector-c Repo        : appstream Matched from: Filename  : /usr/bin/mysql_config

mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.1.13-3.el9.x86_64 : Development files for mariadb-connector-c Repo      : appstream Matched from: Filename  : /usr/bin/mysql_config

mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.2.6-1.el9.i686 : Development files for mariadb-connector-c Repo     : appstream Matched from: Filename  : /usr/bin/mysql_config

mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.2.6-1.el9.x86_64 : Development files for mariadb-connector-c Repo       : appstream Matched from: Filename  : /usr/bin/mysql_config
```

In my case, I selected `mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.2.6-1.el9.x86_64` so i installed it using dnf `dnf install mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.2.6-1.el9.x86_64`

Afterwards I was able to install mysqlclient properly.
I think the problem is that `mysql-devel`  is no longer supported on the newer versions of CentOS

Thanks for your help everyone.