# How to install mysqlclient in a python:3-slim Docker image without bloating the image?

Tags: python, docker, mysql-python

I'm using `python:3-slim` Docker image and want to use the mysqlclient package from Pypi but getting the following error from `RUN pip install mysqlclient` command:

```
...
Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 89.5/89.5 kB 2.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f_fea8lo/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f_fea8lo/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f_fea8lo/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 48, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 27, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.12-slim

RUN pip install mysqlclient
```

I tried installing the build dependencies by adding the following to the Dockerfile above `RUN pip install mysqlclient`:

```
RUN apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

but this took the Docker image to over 700MB. I also tried replacing the line above with the following to remove the build dependencies after install `mysqlclient`:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get dist-upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y pkg-config default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        build-essential libmariadb-dev && \
    pip install mysqlclient && \
    apt-get purge -y pkg-config default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

but the resulting image was still over 500MB in size and took a lot of precious CI/CD build time as it installs and then uninstalls the build tools.

**How do I install `mysqlclient` without bloating my docker image with build dependencies?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Multi-Stage build Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.12 AS python-build
RUN pip install mysqlclient

FROM python:3.12-slim
COPY --from=python-build /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmariadb3
```

This first 'stage' uses a full-fat `python:3.12` image, which has the necessary build tools to install and compile `mysqlclient`. As is typical with Python, the mysqlclient package along with its dependencies are installed in `/usr/local/lib/python*/site-packages`.

Then the build starts again, this time using `python:3.12-slim` image. The `COPY` references the first image and copies just the installed Python packages including `mysqlclient`.
The final line installs `libmariadb3`, which is required by `mysqlclient`, otherwise you'll receive the following error:

```
ImportError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Your image size should now be a little over **190MB**. You'll find it'll build much quicker too.