# Upgraded to Mavericks, now errors with python MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, pip

How do I install MySQL python through pip?

I recently upgraded to Mavericks and now none of my packages and dependencies are working.
I was successfully able to install pip via python ez_setup.py which i found from here [Can't install via pip because of egg_info error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error)

But still keep getting this error.

```
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB): 108kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python/setup.py) egg_info for package MySQL-python
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found

Traceback (most recent call last):
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/xl/lsdkfj09485039845/T/pip_build_Name/mysql-python
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Name/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

I also tried running the command line; export path command I found in here.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download the shell script found here
http://www.macminivault.com/mysql-mavericks/

copy and paste the contents into as a .sh file i named mine `fixeverything.sh`

then from terminal run `sh fixeverything.sh`

then i ran this command to link mysql

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```