# Using MariaDB with Django 1.10 and Python 3.5

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, mariadb

I want to migrate my database from SQLite to MariaDB. Running Ubuntu 14.04, Django 1.10 and Python 3.5. [Digital Ocean has a guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04), but it silently assumes one is using Python 2.x, not 3.x. They use the default mySQL connector, MySQLdb. This does not work for python 3.x. [According to Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers), the preferred alternative is mysqlsclient:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

But this gives:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.9.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error
  Complete output from command /django/env/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3_5btd8o/mysqlclient/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp39x31avopip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,9,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.9 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/django/env/include/python3.5m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/_mysql.o -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -DNDEBUG
  _mysql.c:40:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include "Python.h"
                      ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /django/env/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3_5btd8o/mysqlclient/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qfim2s5n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /django/env/include/site/python3.5/mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,9,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.9 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/django/env/include/python3.5m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/_mysql.o -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -DNDEBUG
    _mysql.c:40:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/django/env/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3_5btd8o/mysqlclient/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qfim2s5n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /django/env/include/site/python3.5/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3_5btd8o/mysqlclient/
```

Not sure why it's partially duplicated.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885914/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-on-ubuntu-14-04-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu), the solution to such `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` errors is to install:

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev
```

which I did, but this made no difference.

Then I tried a bunch of other stuff, including:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev python-dev
```

Which gave:

```
libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.52-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 5.5.52+maria-1~trusty is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I found [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/223267/573611) where it was said that `aptitude` is more useful than `apt-get` and that one can see a list of held packages with:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

But nothing is returned when running this. Trying aptitude gives:

```
(env) user@computer:/$ sudo aptitude install libmysqlclient-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient-dev{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 179 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/866 kB of archives. After unpacking 5,604 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmariadbclient-dev : Conflicts: libmysqlclient-dev but 5.5.52-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed.
                        Conflicts: libmysqlclient15-dev which is a virtual package.
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.52-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 5.5.52+maria-1~trusty is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libmysqlclient-dev [Not Installed]
```

It looks like a conflict between mysql and mariaDB based packages. So I found:

```
pip install libmariadbclient-dev
```

Which installs fine, but the error is still there when trying to install mysqlclient.

How do I get MariaDB to work with Django 1.10 and Python 3.5?

Comment: Since you are using Python 3, you need `python3-dev` instead of `python-dev`.

Comment: Just writing to let you know I didn't forget about this. I just haven't had the time to try it out yet.

Comment: `python3-dev` was already installed. Not the problem.

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue while i was executing

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Then i found out i had to install python3-dev packages, but they were resolving into python3.6 and i was using python3.4 in my virtualenv.

All i had to do was:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev
```