# Error using pip to install MySQL-python

Tags: python, pip, mysql-python

I am trying to install `MySQL-python` on my ubuntu server. Have `Python 2.7` installed. I tried: `sudo pip install MySQL-python` and I am getting the error:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Eu0iVS/MySQL-python`.

Has anyone come across this and knows how to go about fixing it? thanks

Comment: It seems like mysql config is missing in your computer, try this `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` and then `sudo pip install MySQL-python`

Comment: awesome works now thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install mysql-python fails with EnvironmentError: mysql\_config not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found)