# Rails on OSX 10.11 El Capitan: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

Since I upgraded OSX to 10.11, I can't use MySQL with my Rails app anymore:

```
$ rails s
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@a4aa2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': dlopen(/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@a4aa2/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@a4aa2/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@a4aa2/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@a4aa2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@a4aa2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@a4aa2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
```

I found other posts about similar issues, but I'm too much of a beginner in this respect, and versions changed since solving, etc.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The previous answer (pre El Capitan), was to create a symbolic link from mysql's lib directory for the library file into /usr/lib, like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

However this now produces 'operation not permitted' due to OS X's integrity controls.  This can be worked around by disabling this. However a much easier solution (and one I can verify has worked) is to just symlink it into /usr/local/lib instead:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Good ol' Apple.

Comment: Working. Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you're using Python within a virtual env you might need to recreate it or change the paths around since it may still be referring to the /usr/lib version which doesn't exist.

Comment: libmysqlclient.18.dylib doesnt exist for me. All what I see is libmysqlclient.20.dylib. However, MySQL-python still expects libmysqlclient.18.dylib.

Comment: it gives me no such file or directory found

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem just open terminal hit:

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

paste the following lines:

```
MYSQL=/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$MYSQL
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and thats it.

Comment: This didn't change a thing for me. I also closed an re-opened the terminal to make sure it's properly loaded.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue today - did you get to the bottom of it.