# Error loading MySQLdb module: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, mysql, django

I had a running django project and for some reasons I had to remove the current mysql version and install a different MySQL version in my machine.

But now when I am trying to run this program am getting an error as follows:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

reinstall the c shared library:

```
pip uninstall mysql-python
pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: This works for Ruby on Rails projects as well. Comment `gem 'mysql2'` in the Gemfile, run `bundle install`, uncomment the line and run `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 18):

My issue with the same error message was mysql environment not all the way set up. I needed to uninstall MySQL-python; install libmysqlclient-dev; reinstall MySQL-python to rectify the issue.

So the fix was too:

- sudo pip uninstall MySQL-python (uninstall from your package manager of choice)
- sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
- sudo pip install MySQL-python

**I should also mention that I used the --no-cache-dir option with pip install to hit PYPI directly which helped discover the following:

```
sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-Y7RFpJ/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-Y7RFpJ/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "/tmp/pip-build-Y7RFpJ/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

and lead me to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found)

Using: mysql 5.7, mysql-python 1.2.5, django 1.8.9, ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Good observation on the `--no-cache-dir` option!

Answer (score 2):

Use the following commands:

```
pip uninstall mysql-python
pip install mysql-python
```

In my case it work because it searches from the complied files.

Comment: Please give the user who asked more information and details for your answer

Answer (score 2):

I did fix the same issue via setting below environment variable:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

Comment: That worked for me !, thanks

to elaborate more how to find the path i asked yum ( in using ami linux ) by using:  
yum whatprovides "*libmysqlclient*" from the output i couldl find the library folder that had libmysqlclient.so and added it to LB_LIBRARY_PATH on my bash_profile 

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/mysql57

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was caused by Ubuntu upgrades, so I can't find `libmysqlclient.so.20` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Solution:

1. Check existance `libmysqlclient.so.XX` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (or similar)
2. Download `libmysqlclient.so.XX` from Ubuntu website (eg. [link for v20](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libmysqlclient20))
3. Install lib using dpkg command `sudo dpkg -i libmysqlclient(...).deb` and `sudo apt-get install -f`
4. Link lib: `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.XX.so libmysqlclient.XX.so`

Comment: Lukasz, I just posted a very similar but slightly simpler answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/623845/7155

...in case you need to do it again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I fixed making what the mysqlclient official [doc](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient#linux) says to install before:
`sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential`

Answer (score 0):

just in case `pip uninstall` & `pip install` not working, and you dont want to set specific path to `ld_library_path`, what I did on my vps:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s /path/to/your/libmysqlclient.so.20
```

in my case my mysql is installed from linuxbrew (there is some reason to install inside home), so I had to navigate there `$HOME/.linuxbrew/Cellar/mysql/5.7.18/lib/libmysqlclient.so.20`

Answer (score 0):

Just installing these packages works for me :

```
default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```