# I am having an issue while using Python SQLAlchemy in AWS Lambda Service

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Code works fine in virtual environment and I am deploying code correctly with all the dependencies but when my code tries to execute an SQL raw query using SQLAlchemy, I get this

```
{
"stackTrace": [
[
  "/var/task/aws_handler.py",
  13,
  "twilio_handler",
  "sms_bot.handle_communication(message_body, recipient)"
],
[
  "/var/task/sms_bot.py",
  86,
  "handle_communication",
  "is_authenticated, user_id = self.authenticate_user(recipient)"
],
[
  "/var/task/sms_bot.py",
  38,
  "authenticate_user",
  "result = execute_query(query)"
],
[
  "/var/task/db_handler.py",
  28,
  "execute_query",
  "connection = get_db_connection()"
],
[
  "/var/task/db_handler.py",
  19,
  "get_db_connection",
  "return get_sqlalchemy_engine().connect()"
],
[
  "/var/task/db_handler.py",
  11,
  "get_sqlalchemy_engine",
  "return create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)"
],
[
  "/var/task/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py",
  386,
  "create_engine",
  "return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)"
],
[
  "/var/task/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py",
  75,
  "create",
  "dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)"
],
[
  "/var/task/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py",
  92,
  "dbapi",
  "return __import__('MySQLdb')"
],
[
  "/var/task/MySQLdb/__init__.py",
  19,
  "<module>",
  "import _mysql"
]
  ],
   "errorType": "ImportError",
   "errorMessage":
   "libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object  file: No such 

    file or directory"}
```

**NOTE: SQL_URI is correct and working locally**

Comment: try uninstall and re-install mysql python :

pip uninstall mysql-python
pip install mysql-python
Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348752/error-loading-mysqldb-module-libmysqlclient-so-20-cannot-open-shared-object-fi

Comment: Is `libmysqlclient.so.20` inside your deployment package?

Comment: No it's not in my deployment package. How can I include it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, installed

> libmysqlclient-dev

on my computer and copied

> libmysqlclient.so.20

from

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

to my aws deployment package, changed the permissions to 777, compressed all files and uploaded to aws. It worked.