# Error with pip install MySQL-python

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

I have been trying for a few days to fix this, looking at other questions but I can't find a question wth the same error that I am getting.

I have been attempting to follow this tutorial https://realpython.com/learn/start-django/ and get to this point:

Database settings
First, install MySQL-python, which is a database connector for Python:

```
$ pip install MySQL-python
```

Everything has worked okay up to here but when I try and install MySQL-python I get the following error:

> ```
> (env) Camerons-MacBook-Pro:django15_project camrail$ pip install MySQL-python
> Collecting MySQL-python
>   Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>     sh: mysql_config: command not found
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>       File "/private/var/folders/3v/czm4shrx0yg5jts39qktf6t00000gn/T/pip-build-2rNsQQ/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
>         metadata, options = get_config()
>       File "/private/var/folders/3v/czm4shrx0yg5jts39qktf6t00000gn/T/pip-build-2rNsQQ/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
>         libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
>       File "/private/var/folders/3v/czm4shrx0yg5jts39qktf6t00000gn/T/pip-build-2rNsQQ/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
>         raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
>     EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
>     ----------------------------------------
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3v/czm4shrx0yg5jts39qktf6t00000gn/T/pip-build-2rNsQQ/MySQL-python/
> (env) Camerons-MacBook-Pro:django15_project camrail$
> ```

I found this answer https://opensourcehacker.com/2011/03/02/installing-mysql-python-connector-on-osx/ that says the MySQL utilities are not made available, so I followed their advice to fix it but to no avail.  I have also tried installing developer tools `xcode-select --install` as some have suggested.  I have tried reinstalling `ez_setup`.

Not really sure where to go from here, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found

Comment: Check this out for mac osx: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12621216/758667

Comment: Thanks guys, specifically this worked: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Answer (score 12):

In my opinions mysql_config is missing on your system or the installer could not find it. Please Be sure mysql_config is really installed.

For instance,

- On Debian/Ubuntu, You must install the package:
  sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
- Running Mac OSX Mountain Lion, I simply ran this in terminal to fix:
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin

This is the quickest fix I found.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same error while installing the mysql package by pip But after installing libmysqlclient-dev

- sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
- pip install mysql

Now it worked for me..

verified:

> > > import mysql

- did not find any error, Means got installed successfully and working
  properly

Answer (score 1):

Check your mysql configuration file using this:

```
mysql_config
```

Now you should get an output something like this:

```
mysql_config 
Usage: /usr/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Compiler: GNU 6.3.0
Options:
        --cflags         [-I/usr/include/mysql ]
        --cxxflags       [-I/usr/include/mysql ]
        --include        [-I/usr/include/mysql]
        --libs           [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -ldl]
        --libs_r         [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -ldl]
        --plugindir      [/usr/lib/mysql/plugin]
        --socket         [/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock]
        --port           [0]
        --version        [5.7.18]
        --libmysqld-libs [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqld -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -lcrypt -ldl -laio -llz4 -lnuma]
        --variable=VAR   VAR is one of:
                pkgincludedir [/usr/include/mysql]
                pkglibdir     [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
                plugindir     [/usr/lib/mysql/plugin]
Ideally it should contain libmysqld-libs option. If it is not there, as it was not there in my case, you can assume that your mysql is broken.
```

In this case you can write this configuration to config file directly

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Windows OS` download and install `mysql-python` directly from [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/27/06/596ae3afeefc0cda5840036c42920222cb8136c101ec0f453f2e36df12a0/MySQL-python-1.2.5.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=6f43f42516ea26e79cfb100af69a925e) .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it useful. But it help me to solve the problem.

```
apt-get install build-essential zlib1g zlib1g-dev zlibc libxml2 libxml2-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, on Debian Stretch the pkg is now called *default-libmysqlclient-dev*.

```
sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: that one worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I run the following commands and it worked smooth in Ubuntu 17.10

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
pip3 install mysqlclient
```