# Error installing mysqlclient inside virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip

```
(my_project) [yw@yanbox my_project]$ pip install mysqlclient

File "/tmp/pip-build-zza957yo/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-zza957yo/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install mysql-python fails with EnvironmentError: mysql\_config not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `mysql_config` is installed in your system (e.g. run `locate mysql_config`). It's usually provided by the `libmysqlclient` package or similar, depending on your distribution.

If it's present, try providing the path to it to `pip`, e.g.:

```
PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH pip install mysqlclient
```