# having trouble installing flask-mysqldb and functools to my app engine environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app that I am writing purely in the google cloud app engine environment and have a couple of requirements that fail to install. Flask-mysqldb and functools.

I was wondering if you could help me with them. This is what happens when i try to install functools

> Collecting functools Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/3c/33589bf30422a92cf8c77054f2cf940ef2acc8a2857e5664045ed75a1c6a/functools-0.5.tar.gz
>   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File "", line 1, in  File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/init.py", line 4,
>   in  import functools File "functools.py", line 72, in 
>   globals()['c_%s' % x] = globals()[x] = getattr(_functools, x)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose' Command
>
> ---
>
> *"python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in*
>   */tmp/pip-install-Oqd8QA/functools/*

and this is what happens when I try to install Flask-mysqldb:

> Collecting flask-mysqldb Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/e3/955c845efe1aacf30c8e2607470544ede36aa1044f6382c809f13e014104/Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz
>   Collecting Flask>=0.10 (from flask-mysqldb) Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e7/08578774ed4536d3242b14dacb4696386634607af824ea997202cd0edb4b/Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting mysqlclient (from flask-mysqldb) Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz
>   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: sh: 1:
>   mysql_config: not found Traceback (most recent call last): File "",
>   line 1, in  File "/tmp/pip-install-i07vlu/mysqlclient/setup.py", line
>   18, in  metadata, options = get_config() File "setup_posix.py", line
>   53, in get_config libs = mysql_config("libs_r") File "setup_posix.py",
>   line 28, in mysql_config raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" %
>   (mysql_config.path,)) EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
>
> ---
>
> *Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in*
>   */tmp/pip-install-i07vlu/mysqlclient/*

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install mysql-python fails with EnvironmentError: mysql\_config not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found)

Comment: that's possible, should i be installing functools32?  Might need to rewrite some of my code however.

Comment: cool, I think that worked!  Thank you.

any knowledge on flask-mysqldb?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @snakecharmerb for the helpful answer, the cause of the issue might have been that the last released version of functools package was around 2005 ([functools release history, last dated 2005](https://pypi.org/project/functools/#history)) , so changing the import statement (as snakecharmerb mentioned) to `import functools32 as functools` should work as it would just redirect the reference.

For the error you are receiving while installing the Flask-mysqldb, as @serbia99 previously mentioned that it could be happening because of the possible duplication. Please it might be helpful to check if mysql_config is missing, also please try `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` as it would populate the missing configuration file. It solved similar issues in the past for multiple cases. Thanks!

Comment: yep! that wa very helpful.  As for the mysqldb part.  That looks to be something wrong with google app engine.  Had to rewrite my code to use sqlalchemy instead.  And even that has come with its own set of problems.