# Error with pip and installing mysql-python

Tags: python, ubuntu

I cannot seem to understand why I am getting this issue whenever I am running the command `pip install MySQL-python` in Ubuntu. This is what I am getting.

```
pip install MySQL-python
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. 
Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that 
date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting MySQL-python
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-dggKCf/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-dggKCf/MySQL-python/
```

Comment: You should probably check this thread -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install mysql-python fails with EnvironmentError: mysql\_config not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Your version of python is close to the end, so you are invited to upgrade your python's version.
Mysql-python needs this old version of python and become deprecated.