# Docker-compose gives error when downloading mysqlclient

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am getting this error when building my docker-compose.yml. I have a django project and when I try to install its dependencies I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_okt_256/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_okt_256/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9yseytwi
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-_okt_256/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-_okt_256/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-_okt_256/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 65, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-_okt_256/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
        raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Below is my requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.2.10
astroid==2.4.2
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
defusedxml==0.6.0
Django==3.0.8
django-common-helpers==0.9.2
django-cron==0.5.1
django-templated-mail==1.1.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
idna==2.10
install==1.3.3
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
mysqlclient==2.0.1
oauthlib==3.1.0
pylint==2.5.3
pylint-plugin-utils==0.6
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
toml==0.10.1
urllib3==1.25.9
wrapt==1.12.1
```

Error is popped up while downloading mysqlclient.

Someone help

docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'djangodatabase'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '12345'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '12345'
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Here is my Docker File:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Comment: There is some dependencies missing check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found

Comment: @SergioTanaka, I have checked this question but can't figure it out. My project works perfectly locally. I have used all the dependencies

Comment: paste your compose file, you need to install the `libmysqlclient-dev` in your container

Comment: @SergioTanaka: I have added the file

Comment: try to run `docker-compose build` -> `docker-compose run web apt update` and `docker-compose run web apt install libmysqlclient-dev`  -> `docker-compose up`

Comment: @SergioTanaka: getting "**Unable to locate package libmysqlclient-dev**" when running docker-compose run web apt install libmysqlclient-dev

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql\_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)

Comment: also paste the content of your Dockerfile please

Comment: @SergioTanaka, pasted the content of the Dockerfile

Comment: @PalashGoel, I'm new to dockerization, how do I install those dependencies using my docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: look at my answer

Comment: @SergioTanaka, sure, thanks, updating the code and building it

Comment: @SergioTanaka, again getting the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code/
```

Fixed the issue by adding default-libmysqlclient-dev dependency in my docker file.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your Dockerfile the dependencies below

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code/
```

It will work