# pip3 install mysqlclient got error in centos ec2 instance

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, centos

pip3 install mysqlclient got error in centos ec2 instanceERROR: Command

```
errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ewu2x4x2/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ewu2x4x2/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-bc7b78u8
             cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ewu2x4x2/mysqlclient/
        Complete output (12 lines):
        /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
        /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
        /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/tmp/pip-install-ewu2x4x2/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
            metadata, options = get_config()
          File "/tmp/pip-install-ewu2x4x2/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 65, in get_config
            libs = mysql_config("libs")
          File "/tmp/pip-install-ewu2x4x2/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
            raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
        OSError: mysql_config not found
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Please help to install mysql client in centos

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install mysql-python fails with EnvironmentError: mysql\_config not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to install the underlying CentOS MySQL package for development headers.

Try: `sudo yum install mysql-devel`, and then `pip3 install mysqlclient` again.