# Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. Can anyone asssist

Tags: python, django

Can somebody help me to resolve the following error, please?

**The Error message:**

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python2.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3zeNQM/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3zeNQM/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-41RbUT
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-3zeNQM/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-3zeNQM/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try going through answers [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found?rq=1)
It looks like something's wrong with your sql installation or declaration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).